# Why do we have to define states in root component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React. I don't understand why we have to define states in the root component a.k.a in App.js .
İf I have a card component and I only have a state related to the card component should I define it in root component or card component? Can you help me to understand this logic?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Is the state local to the card itself? If so, you can store it there.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Each component can have its own **local** state. There is no such thing as "You should define your state in App".

It's **different than a global** state which will need a different approach depending on the library you are using, but since you are learning react you will comme across this soon with the context Api, Redux, MobX, etc.

For your card example, you can have a local state in your card component, but you might want to manage your array of cards' data in the **parent** (Not App, just one layer above) if you need to do operation like sorting/filtering your cards for example. It just depend on what you need to do with your data.

Comment: I get it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

The reason for declaring React states in the parent components rather than the children component is when the state somewhat relates to multiple components at once.

For example, take a look at this structure:

```
+--------------------+
| App.js             |
| +----------------+ |
| | Title.js       | |
| +----------------+ |
|                    |
| +----------------+ |
| | Description.js | |
| +----------------+ |
+--------------------+
```

And here's our data:

```
const getData = () => {
  return {
    title: "some title",
    description: "some description"
  };
};
```

If you're trying to render this data with the structure we have, then the state has to be on the `App.js` layer and we'll need to pass the data into `<Title/>` and `<Description/>`.

In your example, if the state is strictly for the `Card` component, you should be able to declare a state inside the `Card` component without any issues.

In my opinion, states should only need to be on the parent level if they're being used in multiple children.